# GetTextExtentPoint32 Doesn't Take Account of the Current Font

Tags: c++, winapi, text

I need to find the width of a string with any font. However, when I use `GetTextExtentPoint32`, it doesn't take the account of the current font. This is my code:

```
HFONT hFont = CreateFont(36, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, 
    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, NULL);

SelectObject(GetDC(m_hSettingsWnd), hFont);
GetTextExtentPoint32(GetDC(m_hSettingsWnd), TITLE_TEXT, wcslen(TITLE_TEXT), &sTextSize);
// TITLE_TEXT is the string I'm trying to get the width of.
```

Could anybody correct the formatting as well, please? I'm new to Stack Overflow and the code sample isn't working properly for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SelectObject(GetDC(m_hSettingsWnd), ...);
GetTextExtentPoint32(GetDC(m_hSettingsWnd), ...);
```

By using `GetDC()` in that manner, you are creating resource leaks. Each call to `GetDC()` must be followed by a call to `ReleaseDC()`.  And each call to `GetDC()` creates a separate `HDC`, which is why `GetTextExtentPoint32()` does not know about your font, as you have not selected it into that second `HDC`.

Correct usage of `GetDC()` should fix the font problem. Make sure to also restore the old font before you free the `HDC`:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
const wchar_t *buf = L"buf";
HFONT hFont = CreateFont(36, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, 
    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, NULL);

SIZE size;
HFONT oldfont = (HFONT) SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, buf, wcslen(buf), &size);

SelectObject(hdc, oldfont);
DeleteObject(hFont);

ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
```